Unable to change Terminal fonts in vscode (Windows - WSL Ubuntu)
Problem
I am aware about the approach for changing fonts, however it seems I am unable to change fonts in WSL Ubuntu from Windows Desktop. (It fallbacks to one of the legacy fonts (looks like monospace))
Here are some of the user settings that I changed:
  "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'MesloLGS NF'",
OR
  "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'JetBrainsMono Nerd Font'",
But terminal text doesn't seem to be reflecting anything. I don't seem to have enough internet points to post image here. Please refer to the images from this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78775930/unable-to-change-terminal-fonts-in-vscode-windows-wsl-ubuntu

Tried

I tried reloading the workspace but that didn't work
I tried changing the text of the exact font, (changing spacing, capitalization etc) didn't work
I tried to change the font size (to see if the problem is extended, but turns out that workflow is working as expected)


Expected

My font should change.


Does it happen if you use Windows Terminal?

What terminal are you using? By this I mean, when you open your start menu what are you typing? "WSL" ? Or "Terminal" ?
The Windows Terminal has more customisation features and is a lot easier to use in this sense if this is what you are looking for. Using WSL, you probably have to modify a bunch of configuration files which is tedious. Just use windows terminal, press "ctrl+,", scroll down to WSL, and modify your font settings there.
https://i.imgur.com/sKeJirK.png

Are you using the new terminal host or the legacy terminal host and I still wonder about Windows Terminal.

@jabroni yes Windows terminal is working as expected. i.e. my fonts are getting rendered there, as I have installed them in my windows machine.

@Ramhound we could be close there, as I am not sure what host I am using. Can we change the host of terminal inside vs-code?

I think I got the issue. I was installing fonts on ubuntu, but the fonts gets rendred from the host machine i.e. windows. (I noticed I changed the font to Cascadia mono, it changes)

But only fonts ending with Mono are applicable to be changed? Not sure why that's happening (can't seem to change it to "JetBrainsMono NF")

Restarting VS-code did the trick.

I am so confused as to what you are trying to do here now... you said it works in windows terminal? Why not just use ubuntu wsl via windows terminal then?

here are some key points which might help you.

Make sure you have the font present at the "host" OS. In our case, we need to have the font present in Windows. (Doesn't matter we have it in Ubuntu or not)
Make sure you are typing font "family" and not complete font face.
Try adding different fonts across your library.
If the change are not apparent, restart the VS-code. It needs restart if you have installed the font while the vs-code was open.


Is this a solution, or a list of tips? Did one or more of these actually solve the problem that you presented? Because this post does not make it clear that these have resolved the issue.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You don't need to type anything, it's safer to just choose the font in the setting dropdown. All that is needed is installing and loading font on the system where VSCode is running.
